# visual basic writing into files

Tags: visual-studio, streamwriter

when i want write into a file with visual basic its says he cant becous its already in another procces buts nothings else has op it.
her is my code.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Visible = False
        Label1.Visible = False
        pathlocation.Visible = True
        Button2.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pathlocation.Visible = False
        Button2.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim path As String
        Dim modsl As String = "/modshop"
        Dim config As String = "/config"
        Dim configfile As String = "/config.txt"
        Dim configwriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
        path = pathlocation.Text
        path = path + modsl
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(path)
        config = path + config
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(config)
        configfile = config + configfile
        File.Create(configfile)
        configwriter = File.AppendText(configfile)
        configwriter.Write(path)
        configwriter.Close()
        Button2.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub pathlocation_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pathlocation.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.Create creates the file and returns a FileStream, thus the following File.AppendText finds the file already opened by yourself and fails

You could simplify a lot your code considering this and the fact that [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) method builds all the missing directories in the path passed

```
Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathlocation.Text, "modshop")
Dim fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "config")
Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath)
Dim configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(fullPath, "config.txt")
File.WriteAllText(configFile, path)
```

Following the logic of your code I have used [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) that creates or overwrite the configFile if it exists. If you want to append to an existing file without overwriting its contents then use [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: tha he gives this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30980 Type of 'path' cannot be inferred from an expression containing 'path'. modshop F:\modshop\modshop\Form1.vb 21 Active

Comment: I see, the problem is caused by the class Path in System.IO and the variable named path. You could change that variable name (to filePath for example) or add to the Path class the full namespace System.IO. Updating the answer with the last option

Comment: thanks for helping it works but what if i want write line by line

Comment: _using writer = new StreamWriter(configFile) writer.WriteLine(path)_